# ColdFusion and AJAX - Updating Database

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, coldfusion

I'm wanting to have a system set up where users can go to a page where there's a list of items that they can rate (say, 1 through 5) from a drop-down. This list is going to get quite long thus it would be much more convenient if they could go through and rank each item without ever having to hit "Save."

I'm **very** much a novice when it comes to AJAX but I figure this can't be *that* difficult. I found [an answer in a different discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15209183/4103070) that I think is quite relevant but it doesn't provide enough information for me to know exactly what to do with it.

In short, how do I use AJAX, in congruence with jQuery and ColdFusion, to update the database without the need for a save/submit button?

**CLARIFICATION:** I should have clarified that the user can rate the items - not rank. Meaning that there's no #1, #2, #3, etc. Instead, each item can be rated on a scale from 1-5.

Currently I'm basing everything off of ".change()" when the user makes a selection in the drop-down. At which point I have two jQuery variables that are set to the "ID" of the item changed as well as its new "rating." I just need to find a way to use these two variables to update the table in the database.

## Update

On the main page, I now have a simple jQuery AJAX post call: `$.post('update.cfc', {ID: inputID, rating: selRat})` that is triggered `.onChange()`. "inputID" is the ID of the entry that I want to update in the database and "selRat" is the selected rating in the drop-down.

```
<cfcomponent output="false">
<cffunction name="updateRating" access="remote" output="false">

    <cfupdate datasource="#session.db#" name="update">
        UPDATE ajaxTest
        SET rating = #FORM.rating#
        WHERE ID = #FORM.ID#
    </cfupdate>

</cffunction>
</cfcomponent>
```

I'm currently getting a `500 (Internal Server Error)`.

Thoughts/suggestions?

Comment: You need some kind of button to change the rankings of the options, right? Maybe a pair that let you move an option up or down the list. Use the click event on those buttons to fire of the save. However, you'll run the risk of multiple clicks to move an item up/down more than one slot overwriting each other. You may be better off with a save button they need to click after they've made their changes.

Comment: You're on the right path. Look up a tutorial on how to use jquery's ajax functions with cold fusion. Come back and ask a specific question if you get really stuck.

Comment: @ClaytonLeis: Thanks for the encouragement! I found you can access variables that were passed through AJAX in ColdFusion just by doing #Form.variable# which helped, I think. I've updated the post with more info. I don't mind receiving hints instead of straight up answers if you'd prefer that. Helps one learn! Thanks again.

Comment: Well they'll have to be just hints from me. I don't know CF :-).

Comment: This is a short cut @Steve but I always use charles or firebug or chrome dev tools to tease out the exact url and params that are being passed by the browser. Once you know that then it's easier to debug. You might also turn your output false to true temporarily and see if you can get CF to stop suppressing the error. Make sure debug is set to verbose in the CF Admin.

Comment: Side note - though it is not required, using named arguments is more typical than accessing the FORM scope directly. By using cfargument you can take advantage of the built in validation features. It also makes the function more flexible, as it does not rely on any particular scope.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried submitting the traditional way to this form to see what happens? You can also add some simple debugging like writing to a file to log the executed attempt?

One thing that stands out to me: Should the `<cfupdate` opening and closing tag be `<cfquery` I don't use cfupdate or cfinsert, but I don't think any cf flavor supports the syntax you're trying to use, which leads me to believe it's an easy mistake.

On another note, that query could be especially dangerous, and sorry to go off on a tangent..

If I submitted "0; DROP TABLE Users" for the value of ID, your Users table disappears (if you have a users table). I could also pass other common table names like Members, News, Pages, Content, CMS, Transactions. (I wouldn't do this, but you never know when another user might.)

There's a really easy solution, `<cfqueryparam>`. I'll let you research the tag, but I'll show you how to alter that particular query.

```
<cfquery datasource="#session.db#" name="update">
    UPDATE ajaxTest
    SET rating = <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_integer" value="#form.rating#">
    WHERE ID = <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_integer" value="#form.id#">
</cfquery>
```

CFQUERYPARAMing your variables stops the risk of this and passes the variable values as text rather than sql.

Comment: Oh wow... I can't believe I made that mistake (the cfupdate instead of cfquery)! Also, thanks for the tip on cfqueryparam, cfqueryparap (relevant username). This was just a test site and database but I need to get in the habit of doing it always.

The "cfupdate" mistake was definitely the initial problem. Now I'm getting a POST error (302 Moved Temporarily) and a GET error (403 Forbidden). So, again, something stupid on my part I'm sure.

Comment: @Steve where is this .cfc page? For testing, put it in a folder all its own with a blank application.cfc and manually fill in #session.db# in your cfquery. like mysite.com/noapp/update.cfc. Use this to start simple and learn. You can also make this function do some sort of error reporting. Also, don't feel bad about missing cfupdate, I looked at your question at least 3 times before I noticed it =P. Funny how that works. Had there been a missing #, my brain would zero in on that. But that highlights why it helps to submit traditionally, CF would have told you to stop 'dat! :)

Comment: If the cfupdate solved the stated problem, mark it as the answer and move on.  If you are having subsequent problems, put them into a new question.